# How to work with both underscore and underscore.string at the same time?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using underscore on my projects, but now I want to extend it a using the [underscore.string](https://github.com/edtsech/underscore.string)

I read their documentation, and it seems I could have problems using both if I don't take the extra measures they say to take:

```
var _  = require('underscore');

// Import Underscore.string to separate object, because there are conflict functions (include, reverse, contains)
_.str = require('underscore.string');

// Mix in non-conflict functions to Underscore namespace if you want
_.mixin(_.str.exports());

// All functions, include conflict, will be available through _.str object
_.str.include('Underscore.string', 'string'); // => true
```

However, I don't have any idea of how to follow those steps, I need help understanding the steps to work with both and have no trouble using them.

So far, I have done this:

```
<script src="underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="underscore.string.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also another related question, when I manage to work with both, must I always use `_.str`, or only on the conflicted functions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *How-To use underscore.string* is apparently written for usage in node.js, but as you want to use it within html/js you already started right by including those both libraries.

**underscore** will create the `_` var and if that is present, **underscore.string** will extend that by a `str` and `string` property so you may use `_.str` already by including the two files.

```
<script src="underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="underscore.string.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> _.mixin(_.str.exports()) </script>
```

If you add that last line to your includes, you may use any non conflicting method from **underscore.string** which is all but `include`, `contains` and `reverse` according to the [source file](https://github.com/edtsech/underscore.string/blob/master/lib/underscore.string.js).

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is outdated for underscore.string version 3.x and the new version simply exports a global `s` instead of mixin to underscore namespace.  See my answer below for v3.x

Answer (score 5):

In version 3.x simply use the global `s` instead of `_.mixin()` to the underscore namespace.

**[Here are the changelog notes at Underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/blob/master/CHANGELOG.markdown#300)**

This is all you need for version 3.x

```
<script src="underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="underscore.string.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> Usage as Underscore.js or Lo-Dash mixin is now discouraged as there is
>   too many colliding methods

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `_` rather than `_.str` on every function (even conflicted ones), you can dynamically pick between the conflicting methods based on the argument type:

```
(function(_contains, _include) {
    _.mixin(_.str.exports());
    _.mixin({
        reverse: function(obj) {
            if (typeof obj === "string") {
                return _.str.reverse(obj);
            }
            return obj.reverse();
        },
        contains: function(obj, value) {
            if (typeof obj === "string") {
                return _.str.contains(obj, value);
            }
            return _contains.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        include: function(obj, value) {
            if (typeof obj === "string") {
                return _.str.include(obj, value);
            }
            return _include.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
})(_.contains, _.include);
```